# Add total to pivot chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint, charts

I have a set of data of all the stops in the plant here. The data is arranged in columns as followed:

- Column A Fabrication number
- Column B Start Date
- Column C End date
- Column N observation (this is the filter for the graph you are seeing)
- Column X Team (These are the rows in the axis on the graph (team A, B and C)
- Column AM Week number (by using WEEKNUM() on the start date)

All the other columns also contain data, but this data is not used to make the graph. The pivot chart uses column N as filter, column X as column label and column AM as row label.

I'm working with pivot charts in excel and powerpoint (the ones in powerpoint are linked to the ones in excel).

I would like to add the sum of errors after week 52 in the graph, but I can't find an easy way to do this.

I already googled this, but all the solutions seem to be quite elaborate. On google they mostly suggest to modify your data such that you can become a "grand total" and add this to the pivot table or to copy the data in a normal stacked chart, but this will remove the link between the data and the powerpoint presentation.

My question is: Is there an easy built-in solution for this?

[image: Errors per shift]

Comment: please share what you've found, without it it's difficult to understand what's  "quite elaborate" for you. Which version of Excel do you use? Please also share how your raw data and pivot table is organized.

Comment: I'll be busy the next few hours, but i'll try to add all this extra information today! Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: @MátéJuhász, I made an update to the question, is it now clear or should I include some sample data?

Comment: No, probably there is no simpler solution for that. If you share sample data too, then you may receive suggestions how to organize it better, but I don't think you can avoid the calculation before creating the chart.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I made it work by making a table that pulls the data from the pivot table.